# Why when I change the value of array element, the following one changes as well?

Tags: c++

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game. The program asks the user what cell number they want to put the cross on, and then it chooses the correct option. If it notices that the 'cell' chosen is filled, then it returns false and runs again. However, when that happens, the next element after the "filled" cell gets a cross by itself (1,0 is the filled cell and then 1,1 gets `x`).

Look at the function `put`:

```
class Field {
public:
    string arr[3][3] = {
        {"+", "+", "+"},
        {"+", "+", "+"},
        {"+", "+", "+"}
    };
    void print_field();
};

class Game: public Field {
private:
    bool game;
    bool player_turn;

public:
    void put();

    Game() {
        game = true;
        player_turn = true;
    }

    void start_game() {
        while (game) {
            cout << "\n";
            print_field();
            put();
            if (player_turn) {
                player_turn = false;
            }
            else {
                player_turn = true;
            }
        }
    }
};

void Field::print_field() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        };
        cout << "\n";
    };
}

void Game::put() {
    int choice;
    if (player_turn) {
        printf("Choose where you want to put the cross?: ");
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                if (arr[0][0] == "o" || arr[0][0] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[0][0] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                if (arr[0][1] == "o" || arr[0][1] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                    cout << "\tWrite again";                    
                }
                else {
                    arr[0][1] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                if (arr[0][2] == "o" || arr[0][2] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[0][2] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 4:
                if (arr[1][0] == "o" || arr[1][0] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[1][0] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 5:
                if (arr[1][1] == "o" || arr[1][1] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[1][1] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 6:
                if (arr[1][2] == "o" || arr[1][2] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[1][2] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 7:
                if (arr[2][0] == "o" || arr[2][0] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[2][0] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 8:
                if (arr[2][1] == "o" || arr[2][1] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[2][1] = "x";
                    break;
                }
            case 9:
                if (arr[2][2] == "o" || arr[2][2] == "x") {
                    cout << "\tWrite again";
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[2][2] = "x";
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    else if (player_turn == false) {
        int bot = rand() % 10;
        switch (bot) {
            case 1:
                if (arr[0][0] == "o" || arr[0][0] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[0][0] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (arr[0][1] == "o" || arr[0][1] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[0][1] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (arr[0][2] == "o" || arr[0][2] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[0][2] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (arr[1][0] == "o" || arr[1][0] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[1][0] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (arr[1][1] == "o" || arr[1][1] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[1][1] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if (arr[1][2] == "o" || arr[1][2] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[1][2] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if (arr[2][0] == "o" || arr[2][0] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[2][0] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                if (arr[2][1] == "o" || arr[2][1] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[2][1] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                if (arr[2][2] == "o" || arr[2][2] == "x") {
                    player_turn = false;
                }
                else {
                    arr[2][2] = "o";
                    break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game pv;
    pv.start_game();
}
```

Comment: If you do not `break` then the flow _drops_ or _continues_ into the next `case`. You might want to try to simplify your logic instead of using a huge `switch` construct.

Comment: Note: This is what we in the industry sometimes call a <expletive deleted> of a lot of code. Asking questions with a <expletive deleted> of a lot of code makes getting a concise answers much less likely because of the lack of focus. Consider making a [mre] (a MRE) to rein in the scope. The true beauty of the MRE is you'll likely only get part way through making it before you have reduced the noise around the bug to the point where you can see and fix it yourself.

Comment: Note that you can pretty easily create a mapping between a `int x` in `[0, 9]` and the elements of  2 `{0, 1, 2 } x {0, 1, 2 }`: `int index1 = x % 3; int index2 = x / 3;` this would allow you to simplify this ugly `switch`...

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this use of inheritance isn't appropriate. Just make `Field` a member of `Game`; there's nothing accomplished by deriving `Game` from `Field`. Also, consider making the data array `char arr[3][3]` rather than `std::string arr[3][3]`, since the data being stored is just a single character.

Comment: You have put `break` only inside else block in some cases, and hence the behaviour.